# Application folder is not copied into the Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm following [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/) popular tutorial on using `docker-compose` to create a multi-container Docker application with Django and nginx. My host is Ubuntu 14.04. I've defined my containers like this:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web
```

This is the complete Dockerfile for `web`:

```
FROM python:3.5-onbuild
```

This is how I create a machine, build, and run:

```
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
$ eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose -f dev.yml up -d
```

Everything executes smoothly, except the contents of my application folder (`web`) are not actually in the container when it runs. All I see is that Docker tried to copy them during the build:

```
Step 1 : COPY . /usr/src/app
```

I tried adding a `COPY` command to the Dockerfile, but it failed:

```
Step 2 : COPY web /usr/src/app
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: lstat web: no such file or directory
```

The `web` folder is there. What am I doing wrong? How do I get my application into the container?

Comment: Could you provide the full `Dockerfile` please? Also, give a try with the name directory in which your java application is (is it a directory? A jar-file? Anyhow, do not try to upload the **context** of the building process but a specific file/folder instead -- because in any case you do not need the Dockerfile to be copied.).

Comment: That's the full Dockerfile. I did try adding an explicit COPY command to transfer the directory (which contains a Python application), but that failed. Updated my question.

Comment: Do you have a `WORKDIR` command in there somewhere? Also, does the same happen for `ADD` ?

Comment: I tried setting `WORKDIR` and using `ADD`. Same thing. @Auzias: I also tried uploading a subfolder of 'web', but Docker clearly can't find it.

Comment: You cannot `ADD` or `COPY` into an empty image. Unless you try to create an image from scratch (and that is how 1-layer images are created for the empty linux distribution to start, and even for these there is a `FROM scratch`, see the [Dockerfile for debian:jessie](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/blob/7d44cfcf679a8cd9803482305c22c7e1af3fee15/jessie/Dockerfile)).

Comment: @Auzias: This is not an empty image (please see my question). There is a `FROM python:3.5-onbuild` statement.

Comment: Is the directory `web` is present in the directory `Dockerfile` is? Can you show a ls from your directory and add your build command please?

Comment: `Dockerfile` is in the `./web` directory. The build commands are in the question: `docker-compose build`, `docker-compose -f dev.yml up -d`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with nothing being copied over to the image but I'm on windows

Comment: Make sure that `web` isn't by mistake in the `.dockerignore` (which is the problem I had)